# Code works on 2.3.3 but it crash on 4.0.3

Tags: android, sftp, jsch, android-sdk-2.3

I develop an android project.It is about JSCH.I setup a server and i want to connect with android code.I found required code but it works android 2.3.3,i need code or modify for 4.0.3.Code works in 2.3.3 but it crash at 4.0.3.Please help me

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
            session = jsch.getSession("******", "*********",22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");     
            session.setPassword("******");
            session.connect();
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;     
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've refrained from giving us a stack trace, I'm giving this answer with a bit of guessing.

My guess is you're getting a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). This exception occurs on Android 3.0 and above, when you try to use the network on the main UI thread. This also explains why you don't see the exception on Gingerbread.

To fix this, move all networking code into a [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while(true) { i wrote code here but not working   }

Comment: 10-11 21:17:06.545: E/AndroidRuntime(23478): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1528
10-11 21:17:06.545: E/AndroidRuntime(23478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-11 21:17:06.545: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-11 21:17:06.545: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
10-11 21:17:06.545: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
10-11 21:17:06.545: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:234)

Comment: You're using a Toast somewhere causing the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot,but i have another question,my project works on avd manager correctly,but in my phone it doesn't work.avd manage and my phone has same version 4.0.3.what is the reason ? Raghav Sood

Comment: Seeing as that's unrelated to this question, I'd recommend that you open another question for that.